# PIC Programmer driver issue

Tags: microcontroller, pic, software, adapter, error

I'm programming a **PIC16F77** with **ProPic 2** which communicates via serial port. As I don't have this port in my PC, I used serial to USB adapter. I'm using **ICProg** in **Windows 8**.

I've proggrammed it before but it was in Windows XP using the driver who specifies in http://www.ic-prog.com/index1.htm and worked perfectly. But in this OS the only difference is the adapter, the program gives some errors while loading the driver:

> "Error occured (Access is denied) while loading the driver!"
>
> "Privileged instruction"

Comment: This is a better fit on the 'superuser' Stack Exchange site.

Comment: It should be noted that serial programmers like that have a history of playing very, very poorly with USB-serial adapters. They tend to abuse the serial port to generate the voltages they need, and it many usb-serial interfaces don't work well in this kind of situation. YMMV, but don't be surprised if it doesn't work even with the drivers fixed. Really, why not just buy a Microchip Pickit? They're amazingly cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 is not the greatest OS for use with serial ports. I've heard a lot of people having trouble like this, and the only real long-term solution is getting a better programmer, such as the Pickit 3 (highly recommend it since you can also debug with it). You might also get more support in microchip's forums: www.microchip.com/forums

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 will not install unsigned drivers, and won't give you an error message telling you that!  This feels like it might be your problem.  If it is, you can boot into a troubleshooting mode to override this nastiness.  Try http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-can-i-install-hardware-with-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8/ for directions, or just google around for "install win8 unsigned driver" until you find directions you like.  I hope this is your problem, as its not a bad fix.